# What is the logstash "mutate" equivalent in ELasticsearch Ingestion API

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok, filebeat

I am using filebeat-5.2, logstash-5.2 and AWS Elastic Search Service-5.1.
Here I have my existing grok pattern defined in logstash

```
grok{
match => "\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}\]"
}
mutate {
                add_field => {
                                "timestamp" => "\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}\]"
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to define the equivalent grok processor in Ingestion API.

```
    PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipe_celery_log
    {
      "processors": [
        {
     "patterns": ["\\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}\\]"]
 ....................
```

Is there any method so that I can define **mutate** in Ingestion API to extract the fields for my timestamp.

I am pretty new to Ingestion API here. Please help me if anyone could solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processor you are looking for is called `set`.

It looks like this:

```
"set" : {
  "field" : "fieldname"
  "value" : "fielvalue"
}
```

You can access fields with double curly brackets:

```
{{fieldname}}
```

Check out the `set` processor docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/set-processor.html).

Comment: `{
  "set": {
    "field": "timestamp",
    "value":"{{monthday}}/{{month}}/{{year}}:{{time}}"
  }`. This did a trick when run by setting my Elastic Search-5.1.2 locally. My bad its not supporting in AWS managed Elastic Search and I am getting error like ""reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [mustache]",
        "header": {
          "processor_type": "set" ". Any comments on this feature mismatch and any way I can overcome this?

Comment: Looks like they don't support all ingest processors, but don't quote me on that. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html).